# Ошибка Activity

Tags: android, c#, json, парсер, xamarin

Добрый вечер!

Пишу приложение для андроида.
НА данный момент реализую парсер JSON через API сайта.

При загрузке лэйаута  выпадает ошибка `"Application has stopped"`.

Ни Visual Studio ни Xamarin не показывает ошибок в коде. В чем трабл?

Собственно вот мой код:

```
public class SushiActivity : Activity 
{

protected async override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    // Create your application here
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Sushilayout);
    string url = "http://new.murakami.ua/?mkapi=getProducts";
    JsonValue json = await FetchAsync(url);
    ParseAndDisplay(json);

    ImageButton logo = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.logoButton);
    ImageButton previous = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.previousButton);
    ImageButton home = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.homeButton);

    ImageButton cart = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.cartButton);

    //otslezivaem click po knopke "Previous" i perehodim na nee
    previous.Click += delegate
    {
        var intent26 = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        StartActivity(intent26);
    };
    //Otslezivaem click po knopke "Home" i perehodim na glavnuu
    home.Click += delegate
    {
        var intent27 = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        StartActivity(intent27);
    };
    //Otslezivaem click po knopke "Logo" i perehodim na glavnuu
    logo.Click += delegate
    {
        var intent28 = new Intent(this, typeof(MainActivity));
        StartActivity(intent28);
    };
    cart.Click += delegate
    {
        var intent29 = new Intent(this, typeof(CartActivity));
        StartActivity(intent29);
    };
}

private async Task<JsonValue> FetchAsync(string url)
{
    // Create an HTTP web request using the URL:
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.Method = "GET";

    // Send the request to the server and wait for the response:
    using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
    {
        // Get a stream representation of the HTTP web response:
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            // Use this stream to build a JSON document object:
            JsonValue jsonDoc = await Task.Run(() => JsonObject.Load(stream));
            //dynamic data = JObject.Parse(jsonDoc[15].ToString);
            //Console.Out.WriteLine("Response: {0}", jsonDoc[0].ToString);

            // Return the JSON document:
            return jsonDoc;
        }
    }
}
private void ParseAndDisplay(JsonValue json)
{
    // ImageView product = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.productimage);
    TextView productname = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.posttittle);
    JsonValue firstitem = json[15];
    //Console.Out.WriteLine(firstitem["post_title"].ToString());
    productname.Text = firstitem["post_title"];
}
}
}
```

Comment: стактрейс ошибки посмотрите как минимум. Разрешение на интернет в манифест добавлено?

Comment: @metalurgus
ошибок не выдает 

разрешение на интернет стоит

Comment: все, проблема решена

Comment: @Eugene  напишите ответ, в чем проблема и поставьте как правильный

Comment: @Eugene ошибок не выдавать не может, это исключено. Вы можете например не туда смотреть, это более вероятно.